# Comparing strings in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to make a very basic function in google scripts. Basically, I want to read a value from cell J5 and increment the value in L5 until J5 says "Good!" (which would happen based on other stuff in my spreadsheet). I can't seem to test the string though.. when running, the code just seems to stop randomly or run forever (I also need the code to not touch the spreadsheet the moment it says "Good!", otherwise.. everything gets altered since the formulas run again).

```
  function makeSelections() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var testcell = ss.getRange('J5')
      var testcellValue = testcell.getValue();
      for (var i = 0; testcellValue != "Good!"; i++) {
        ss.getRange('L5').setValue(i); 
        testcellValue = testcell.getValue();
      }
    }
```

EDIT: As zbnrg pointed out, it appears to be a problem with the spreadsheet being way too slow to keep up with the script. Can anyone help with code to check a range (A2-A14) for no duplications (i.e. all unique entries)?

Comment: Your codes run fine on my end. When I type "Good!" at J5, the count at L5 stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recalculation of the "other stuff" in the spreadsheet is slower than the for-loop; you might pause the calculation and let the spreadsheet recalculate.  Within the for-loop include:

```
Utilities.sleep(1000); //1000 milliseconds for 1 sec, 2000 for 2, etc.
```

Javascript: fast, Google Spreadsheet recalc: slow, unpredictable

**Update for second part of question**

**Quick and dirty way to randomize a list without fussing with scripts:**

Use =rand(), this generates a random number between 0 and 1:

1. Insert a column before the names in the A column.
2. Put the formula =rand() into A2 and drag it the length of the names
3. Sort both of these rows by the values in column A.  (Doesn't matter if it is ascending or descending, since we just want a randomized list).
4. There you go, randomized names.
5. Then delete the row of random numbers.

Comment: This is definitely the problem as I see it 'overshooting' the mark each time I run it.. can't seem to find a delay long enough though. Even at 5 seconds, it still misses. I guess I need to move some of the calculations over to scripts? Is there an easy way to calculate unique entries in a range?

Comment: What do you mean by 'calculate unique entries'?  The answer is probably yes, and definitely get those dependent calculations into the script if you think you can, it may be simpler than you expect.  That goes for any other time you might have a script and the sheet both 'thinking' at the same time and depending on one another's output.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and help! I have a list of 13 names from A2-A14. Using spreadsheet formulas, I am currently randomizing the list of names but I don't want any names to be repeated. This is where this script came in.. I was basically tricking the spreadsheet into running all its formulas again by just writing into a cell until a formula indicated there was no duplications! I will work on a script to do that last part for me since it should solve the problem! Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the accept! I put a non-scripting solution in my answer above, I think this is really what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks.. not sure that will work for me though simply because it's a little more complicated. Really, I'm taking names from 5 different random lists.. and I don't want any duplicates. I can easily make sure there are no duplicates between the X names I take from one particular list but it's correlating it to the other lists that is the problem.. hence the workaround by 'brute-forcing' it until I get lucky.

Comment: I might just have to write a script for the whole thing since even checking for duplicates via script seems to be too fast for the spreadsheet to keep up. Oh well! More fun coding.